# Finding an item that matches predicate in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, idioms

I'm trying to search a scala collection for an item in a list that matches some predicate. I don't necessarily need the return value, just testing if the list contains it.

In Java, I might do something like:

```
for ( Object item : collection ) {
    if ( condition1(item) && condition2(item) ) {
       return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

In Groovy, I can do something like:

```
return collection.find { condition1(it) && condition2(it) } != null
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this in Scala? I could of course convert the Java loop style to Scala, but I feel like there's a more functional way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about idiomaticity or functionalness: the collections in the Scala library have the `exists` and `find` method (difference is that `find` returns the element) which return as soon as the element is found.  Both are implemented with a `var` and a `while` loop, looking very similar to that java implementation you have (except taking the predicate as parameter).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use filter:

```
scala> val collection = List(1,2,3,4,5)
collection: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

// take only that values that both are even and greater than 3 
scala> collection.filter(x => (x % 2 == 0) && (x > 3))
res1: List[Int] = List(4)

// you can return this in order to check that there such values
scala> res1.isEmpty
res2: Boolean = false

// now query for elements that definitely not in collection
scala> collection.filter(x => (x % 2 == 0) && (x > 5))
res3: List[Int] = List()

scala> res3.isEmpty
res4: Boolean = true
```

But if all you need is to check use `exists`:

```
scala> collection.exists( x => x % 2 == 0 )
res6: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Yep, that looks like the method I was looking for. Still learning Scala...Thanks.

Comment: A bit simpler `collection exists { x => condition1(x) && condition2(x) }`

Comment: @Yep, I've added this one too

Comment: @om-nom-nom, yeah, quite simultaneous :)

Comment: Do `exists()` got a quick exit on first `true`?

Comment: @Stas yes, it `exist` exits (pun intended) on the first `true` occurrence

Answer (score 60):

## Testing if value matching predicate exists

If you're just interested in testing if a value exists, you can do it with.... `exists`

```
scala> val l=(1 to 4) toList
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> l exists (_>5)
res1: Boolean = false

scala> l exists (_<2)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> l exists (a => a<2 || a>5)
res3: Boolean = true
```

Other methods (some based on comments):

## Counting matching elements

Count elements that satisfy predicate (and check if count  > 0)

```
scala> (l count (_ < 3)) > 0
res4: Boolean = true
```

## Returning first matching element

Find the first element that satisfies predicate (as suggested by Tomer Gabel and Luigi Plinge this should be more efficient because it returns as soon as it finds one element that satisfies the predicate, rather than traversing the whole List anyway)

```
scala> l find (_ < 3)
res5: Option[Int] = Some(1) 

// also see if we found some element by
// checking if the returned Option has a value in it
scala> l.find(_ < 3) isDefined
res6: Boolean = true
```

## Testing if exact value exists

For the simple case where we're actually only checking if one specific element is in the list

```
scala> l contains 2
res7: Boolean = true
```

Comment: If you *are* interested in the return value, use findFirst. You can also get the count using the self-named function. All take the same predicate.

Comment: It's `find`, not `findFirst`, but yes that's more efficient than filtering the whole list

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I added Tomer's proposal with your correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The scala way would be to use `exists`:

```
collection.exists(item => condition1(item) && condition2(item))
```

And since java 8 you can use `anyMatch`:

```
collection.stream().anyMatch(item -> condition1(item) && condition2(item));
```

which is much better than a plain for or foreach.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter and exists keywords to get the matching values from Lists**

```
val values = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,....,1000) //List -1
val factors= List(5,7) // List -2

//To get the factors of List-2 from List-1
values .filter(a => factors.exists(b => a%b == 0)) //Apply different logic for our convenience
```

Given code helps to get the matching values from 2 different lists