# Iterating through Seq in Scala and find an element who satisfies the condition

Tags: scala, seq

I am new to Scala and I have a Seq[String] - regex of regexes and I want to iterate through this sequence and if another string, let's call it id, matches at least one of the regexes from the string, to return true.

More clear: to iterate through all of the elements of regex and if (id.matches(regex)) for at least one, then return true, otherwise false).

Can I achieve this with the .map function or creating a find function? Thanks

Comment: [Finding an item that matches predicate in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9556600/432903)

Comment: Simply: `regexs exists id.matches`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `seq.exists(regex => id.matches(regex))`